# Progress bar for svn checkout in text mode

Tags: bash, svn, progress-bar

I'm writing a bash script that needs to fetch source code from several remote subversion repositories. I use `svn checkout -q` to avoid displaying long lists of files that clutter the output but now I'm looking for a clean way to display progress info to the user during each `svn checkout`. Something in the vein of `wget` and `curl`'s progress indicators. I'll have users in OSX and Linux. `pv` is available on both but so far, I haven't found how to use it with `svn checkout`. I should also say that I'm not looking for tools that use GUI windows, but text-only tools.

Any suggestions would be very welcome! Thanks!

Comment: Are you looking to report on progress by byte count, or by file count?

Comment: @alroc I was thinking as a percentage of the whole download but I'm not finding any easy way to determine the total checkout size with `svn`. The total byte count would be the next best thing.

Comment: The byte count is not easy to get with SVN; I don't think the server provides that data to the client as part of the process. File count is your best option I think.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
svn list -v -R URL
```

you can parse the result, and do a progress by file count.

Comment: Exactly what I was going to suggest.

Comment: So how do you get the file count of what's already been fetched? Use `stat`?

Comment: svn co URL > file
and then do a loop with
wc -l file

Comment: I fail to see how that helps. By the time I've done 'svn co URL', everything has been fetched and there's no need for a progress bar...

Answer (score 0):

Closest thing I've found: http://www.danielkraaij.nl/2014/03/30/subversion-progressbar-in-bash/

```
n=$(svn info -R svn://svn/project/trunk | grep "URL: " | uniq | wc -l)
```

---

```
n=$(svn info -R svn://svn/project/trunk | grep "URL: " | uniq | wc -l)
i=1
while read line filename
    do
    counter=$(( 100*(++i)/n))
    echo -e "($counter %)\n"
    echo -e "filename: $filename \n"
done < <(svn co svn://svn/project/trunk /var/www/project)
```

---

```
dialog --backtitle "Subversion Installer" --title "SVN Checkout" --gauge "Getting total file count" 7 120 < <(
    n=$(svn info -R svn://svn/project/trunk | grep "URL: " | uniq | wc -l)
    i=1
    while read line filename
        do
        counter=$(( 100*(++i)/n))
        echo "XXX"
        echo "$counter"
        echo "filename: $filename"
        echo "XXX"

    done < <(svn co svn://svn/project/trunk /var/www/project)
)
```